# highlight selected div when being used as radio button using css

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it was possible to highlight a div with just css when clicked (when div is a label for a radio button) here is my code:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>

        <input type="radio" name="id" value="<?php echo $image['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $image['id']; ?>">
        <label for="<?php echo $image['id']; ?>">   
            <div class="delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?php echo $tableToDeleteFrom;?>"><img src="../images/thumbs/<?php echo $image['name']; ?>"><br>
                <?php echo $image['desc']; ?>
            </div>
        </label>    
<?php } ?>
```

the radio button is obviously currently hidden. the desired effect is to get the div ".delete"'s background to change when one is selected, then when a different one is selected, the new selection is highlighted and the old selection is no longer highlighted. Maybe jquery is the best solution, but I'd be interested to see if there was an easier solution with just css.

Comment: You will need to use JQuery because the CSS will not work in any of the older browsers

Comment: @DavidAguirre rgr that. however what if i dont care? what would the selectors look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, background red

```
input:checked + label div.delete { background: red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector to target the label :

```
input:checked + label{}
```

Be aware that it is not well supported in older browser.

Comment: ok so what would the selector here be if the div is .delete? I'm kind of confused by the syntax...

Comment: It means select all label tag with follow all input which are checked